# Equivalence of different versions of Markov property

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $X_t,t\ge 0$ be continuous, $n$-dimensional process and filtration $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(X_s,0\le s \le t)$. We want to show the equivalence of the two definition in the following:
$$ E[f(X_t)|X_{t_n},\cdots,X_{t_1}] = E[f(X_t)|X_{t_n}] $$
for all $t>t_n>\cdots>t_1\ge 0$ and $f$ is continous, bounded and measurable.

Another definition is,
$$E[f(X_t)|\mathcal{F}_s]=E[f(X_t)|X_s]$$
for all $t>s\ge 0$ and $f$ is continous, bounded and measurable.

I can show from second definition implies first one, but not sure how to show from first to second. I tried the following:
Given that $E[f(X_t)|X_{t_n},\cdots,X_{t_1}] = E[f(X_t)|X_{t_n}]$. Since $E[f(X_t)|X_{t_n}]=E[E[f(X_t)|X_{t_n}]|X_{t_n},\cdots,X_{t_1}]$ and $E[f(X_t)|X_{t_n},\cdots,X_{t_1}]=E[E[f(X_t)|\mathcal{F}_{t_n}]|X_{t_n},\cdots,X_{t_1}]$. Therefore,
$$E[E[f(X_t)|X_{t_n}]|X_{t_n},\cdots,X_{t_1}] = E[E[f(X_t)|\mathcal{F}_{t_n}]|X_{t_n},\cdots,X_{t_1}]$$.

From here, I am not sure if I can conclude that $E[f(X_t)|X_{t_n}] = E[f(X_t)|\mathcal{F}_{t_n}]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume for simplicity that $X_t\in\mathbb{R}$. Note that $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(X_s:s\le t)$ is generated by the collection of cylinder sets
$$
\mathcal{C}_t=\{\{X_{t_1}\in B_1,\ldots X_{t_n}\in B_n\}: n\in \mathbb{N}, B_i\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), t_i\le t\},
$$
and $\mathcal{C}$ is a $\pi$-system ($\because$ it is closed under finite intersections). For $s<t$, let
$$
\mathcal{L}_s=\{A\in \mathcal{F}_s:\mathsf{E}[f(X_t)1_A]=\mathsf{E}[\mathsf{E}[f(X_t)\mid X_s]1_A]\}.
$$
It is clear that $\mathcal{C}_s\subset\mathcal{L}_s$. Thus, by the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem $\mathcal{F}_s=\sigma(\mathcal{C}_s)\subseteq\mathcal{L}_s$. (It remains to show that $\mathcal{L}$ is a Dynkin system.)

Comment: How do you know that $\mathcal{F}_t$ is generated by $\mathcal{C}_t$?

Comment: @TalkingPuppet Check out page 5 [here](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~spieksma/colleges/sp-master/BN.pdf).

Comment: How $\mathcal{C}_s \subset \mathcal{L}_s$? Do you actually mean $\mathcal{L}_s=\{A\in\mathcal{C}_s:\cdots$?

Comment: That's because 
$$
E[f(X_t)|X_{t_n},\cdots,X_{t_1}] = E[f(X_t)|X_{t_n}].
$$

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can I know how would I show that the $\mathcal{L}$ is a $lambda$-system?

Comment: You need to verify properties (L1)-(L3) [here](https://www.math.lsu.edu/~sengupta/7360f09/DynkinPiLambda.pdf). For L3 use the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: How would you show that $C$ is a $\pi$-system?

Comment: My idea is that taking two elements and then taking intersection, and then re-indexing. Maybe I should consider two elements may have two cases:(1) some index are same and can be combined (2) if no index same, then I just have a long intersection?